# Im trying to make a custom GridView Builder widget in flutter , But i'm getting error

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

```dart
class GridViewHzTop extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridViewHzTop({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.iconPath,
    required this.count,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final String iconPath;
  final int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(maxCrossAxisExtent: 110, mainAxisSpacing: 10, crossAxisSpacing: 10),
            itemCount: count,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: aWhiteColor,
                  boxShadow: const [
                    BoxShadow(color: aSecondryColor, blurRadius: 0.1, spreadRadius: 0.25, offset: Offset(0, 0.5)),
                  ],
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          iconPath,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: LargeText(
                        text: text,
                        size: 14,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}


/// list for grid view
class TopSixOptions {
  final String iconPath;
  final String text;

  TopSixOptions(this.iconPath, this.text, this.onPress);

  static List<TopSixOptions> topsixoptions = [
    TopSixOptions('assets/icons/noticepin.png', 'notice', null),
    TopSixOptions('assets/icons/leave.png', 'Leave', null),
    TopSixOptions('assets/icons/schedule.png', 'Schedule', null),
    TopSixOptions('assets/icons/upload.png', 'Upload', null),
    TopSixOptions('assets/icons/leave.png', 'Leave', null),
    TopSixOptions('assets/icons/leave.png', 'Leave', null),
  ];
}

//
final topsixoptions = TopSixOptions.topsixoptions;

SizedBox(
  height: 240,
  child: GridViewHzTop(
    count: topsixoptions.length,
    iconPath: topsixoptions[index].iconPath,
    text: topsixoptions[index].text,
  ),
),
```

getting error

> Undefined name 'index'.
> Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

i'm new in flutter try to make this grid to custom widget so i can used it it again.

I tried to make it reusable widget So i can reuse it on but getting error

Comment: while posting a Question  error and suggestion cmd+ K added Some "\[" added on  code ....

Comment: how you are using last snippet `SizedBox`. can you include more details and snippet

Comment: Im using SizedBox in another .dart file the As far I'm understanding Im trying to access List Index without any  builder thats why Index is unrecognised /undefined ,as its print list length without error but not any index items or index

Comment: another file  on a  widget/just method ?

Comment: i required to use same grid view builder widget 3 time on three pages , as list length , icon , text are not same , i want to reuse it  but  unable to acess any index or index item of list ,

Comment: If i understand your situation correctly, you can pass index as I've posted.

Comment: final topsixoptions = TopSixOptions.topsixoptions;

SizedBox(
  height: 240,
  child: GridViewHzTop(
    count: topsixoptions.length,
    iconPath: topsixoptions[index].iconPath,
    text: topsixoptions[index].text,
  ),                                                in here how can access the icon Path and text from list as error was '[index] is undefined name ' but its shows grid view as many time as the length of index but not the items of list ,

Comment: sorry I am not sure but you can create widget by passing index,

Comment: Because in `GridViewHzTop(
          count: topsixoptions.length,
          iconPath: topsixoptions[index].iconPath,
          text: topsixoptions[index].text,
        )` there is no `index` parameter exists in your code

Comment: maybe i'm unable to explain , u can copy a code and run it ....to understand the error,

Comment: I have added snippet code check if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

First of all to get `index` you will need to iterate the `list<TopSixOptions>`. To solve this you can do like this

```
class GridViewHzTop extends StatelessWidget {
const GridViewHzTop({Key? key, required this.count, required this.list})
  : super(key: key);

final int count;
final List<TopSixOptions> list;
```

add `List<TopSixOptions>` parameter into your `GridViewHzTop` constructor
then inside `GridView.builder` you will get `index` where you can assign the values of `List<TopSixOptions>` to your particular widget like this.

```
 GridView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 110,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10),
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Flexible(
          flex: 3,
          child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Image.network(
          list[index].iconPath,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      );
    })
```

and your `GridViewHzTop` widget will be like this

```
// Assign it separately
List<TopSixOptions> topsixoptions = [
TopSixOptions('assets/icons/noticepin.png', 'notice', null),
TopSixOptions('assets/icons/leave.png', 'Leave', null),
TopSixOptions('assets/icons/schedule.png', 'Schedule', null),
TopSixOptions('assets/icons/upload.png', 'Upload', null),
TopSixOptions('assets/icons/leave.png', 'Leave', null),
TopSixOptions('assets/icons/leave.png', 'Leave', null),
];


SizedBox(
      height: 240,
      child:GridViewHzTop(
      count: topsixoptions.length,
     list: topsixoptions))
```

I hope this will help you [snippet code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c8e02ff5ae11631fd818541a2246c998)